# for any $a$ belongs to $\mathbb{C}$ $f(z_i)=a$ holds for $z_1,z_2,..;z_n$

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that a certain entire function is a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287683/proof-that-a-certain-entire-function-is-a-polynomial)

Let $f$ be an entire function such that for every $a \in \mathbb{C}$ there are $z_1,z_2,.....,z_n \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z_i)=a$. Is $f$ a complex polynomial of degree $n$? Please give me hints.

Comment: Show that $\infty$ is not an essential singularity for $f$ using Picard. This will force $f$ to be a polynomial. Degree $n$ comes from your condition.

Comment: Assuming that the $z_i$ are *distinct*, then no polynomial $p(z)$ satisfies your condition, because after you fix a root $z_0$ of $p^\prime$, then $z_0$ is also a root of the polynomial $q(z)=p(z)-p(z_0)$, which satisfies $q^\prime=p^\prime$. Thus, $z_0$ is a multiple root of $q(z)$, and so the equation $q(z)=0$ has less than $n$ *distinct* roots, that is, $p(z)=p(z_0)$ has less than $n$ distinct roots.

Comment: The question could be clearer, both for the reason Matemáticos mentions and because it does not state that there are *only* $n$ such values. As stated currently, $\sin$ would be a counterexample.  If you mean, exactly $n$, counted according to multiplicity, then yes.

Comment: This is related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287683/proof-that-a-certain-entire-function-is-a-polynomial/287727#287727

Comment: I disagree that the question is duplicated, because in the alleged original question the number $n$ is an *upper* bound for the number of roots, whereas in this case $n$ is a *lower* bound.