# Characterization of entire functions to be a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I need some help with this proposition:

If $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function such that $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:f(z)=w\}$ is finite for all $w\in \mathrm{Im} (f)$ then $f$ is a polynomial.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to avoid big Picard, have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287683

Comment: @ mrf: Unfortunately, Baire's category theorem together with Casorati-Weierstrass one are not simpler than Great Picard's theorem .

Comment: @user64494 That depends. Casorati-Weierstrass is elementary, and if you have taken topology before complex analysis, you probably know Baire's category theorem. Anyway, the OP wanted to avoid big Picard, not necessarily replace it with something simpler.

Comment: @ mrf: You wrote "Anyway, the OP wanted to avoid big Picard, not necessarily replace it with something simpler". I don't see that in the question. This is your personal opinion.

Comment: @mrf See his comment in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f$ is entire then it is a polynomial if and only if it does not have an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

[Great Picard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) implies that statement.

Comment: is necessary to use Picard's theorem?

Comment: @ felipeuni: Maybe, the use of Great Picard's theorem is not necessary to this end.