# If $f$ is meromorphic in $\Bbb{C}$ and $\sup_{w\in \hat{\Bbb{C}}}\# f^{-1}(w)<\infty$ then it is rational

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is meromorphic in $\Bbb{C}$ and $\sup_{\#w\in \hat{\Bbb{C}}}\#f^{-1}(w)<\infty$ then it is a rational function.

Attempt: I should just make sure there is no essential singularity at $\infty$. Suppose there is. Then by the Casorati–Weierstrass theorem I get that in any neighborhood $V$ of $\infty$ (This seems problematic for $\infty$ is not a sensible point.) $f(V\setminus\{\infty\})$ is dense in $\Bbb{C}$. Any complex number can now be approximated by $f(z)$ in any vicinity of $\infty$, and intuitively I see the contradiction, but I am really far from putting it in words and actually showing there are infinitely many point with the same image. I could really use your assistance.

There must be a finite number of poles, meaning that approaching infinity, from some point there are no poles, but still points where $f$ approaches infinity, but I guess it cannot be\approach infinity in a point that is not infinity (can't seem to formalize it), meaning $f$ approaches infinity as $z$ approaches infinity, which is potentially a contradiction. Any thoughts?

**we did not learn about the Picard theorem**

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287683) (stated for an entire function, but it's almost the same).

Comment: Can I avoid baire category?