# entire function with bounded multiplicity is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be an entire function.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and suppose that

$$\forall w\in\mathbb{C}:\#\{z\in\mathbb{C}:f(z)=w\}\leq n$$

In words, every complex value is attained by $f$ in at most $n$ different places.

**Prove** that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287683 for an approach avoiding Picard's great theorem.

Comment: @mrf Your proof at that link is very nice. Don Fanucci, take notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from [Picard's great theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem).

Comment: By considering $\frac 1 f$ ?

Comment: No. Considering $f\left(\frac1z\right)$.

Comment: Ho, now I see. Tend to forgot this surprising theorem, may be because I find it hard understanding it. [+1]

Comment: Oh yes I see, thank you. But, by considering $f(\frac{1}{z})$ I can see that if $f$ is not a polynomial then $z=0$ is an essential singularity, which brings a contradiction to the assumptions using Picard's. But, this only gives that $f$ is a polynomial (without a bound on the degree), then we need to use the local mapping theorem, right?

Comment: You can use the fondamental theorem of algebra for the bound, now that you know that $f$ must be a polynomial.

Comment: Maybe, but the fundamental theorem guarantees $deg(f)$ roots with multiplicities which do not contradict higher degree?

Comment: @DonFanucci If $P(z)$ is a polynomial with degree $n$ and if $|w|$ is large enough, then the equation $P(z)=w$ will have $n$ distinct roots.

Comment: @zhw. Whenever I solve a Complex Analysis exercise using that theorem, I think about how I could solve the exercise without it. In this case, I was unable to find such a way.

Comment: I had removed my comment before I read your last one. Did you see the proof by @mrf?

Comment: @zhw. Cute! I've just upvoted it.