# Entire function is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f = \sum_{n =0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ be an entire function such that $\forall w \in \mathbb{C}, f(z) = w$ admits a finite number of solutions.

I want to prove that f is a polynomial.

So far, I know that $f(z) - w$ admits a finite number of roots, by fixing $w$ I wanted to directly show that it forces $f$ to be a polynomial of maximum degree $n$ (with $n$ being the number of roots).

I don't know how to proceed and any help would be welcome.

Comment: $e^z = w$ has *infinitely many* solutions for all $w \ne 0$.

Comment: @MartinR You are right. I'm still confused on how I should be able to bound the coefficients of $f$ so that its degree is finite.

Comment: I think you should drop "$\forall z \in \mathbb C$". If you fix $z$, then $f(z)$ is fixed as well.

Comment: @red_trumpet: Sorry, it was "$\forall w \in \mathbb{C}$".

Comment: Does this answer your question? – https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287683/42969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for any entire function $f$, the function $g(z) = f(1/z)$ has an isolated singularity at $z = 0$. Looking at the power series expansion $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$ one gets the Laurent series expansion for $g$ at $0$ as
$$g(z) = \sum_{-\infty}^0 a_{-n} z^{n}.$$
So it is clear that $f$ is a polynomial (i.e. has finite power series) if and only if $g$ has a pole at $z=0$, instead of an isolated singularity.

Now the claim follows by Picard's great theorem[1]:

> If an analytic function $f$ has an essential singularity at a point $w$, then on any punctured neighborhood of $w$ , $f ( z )$ takes on all possible complex values, with at most a single exception, infinitely often.

As $g(z) = f(1/z)$, also $g$ takes on each value finitely many often, especially so in each neighbourhood of $z=0$. Hence $g$ cannot have an essential singularity.

---

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem